# Error while trying to begin a job in Hadoop

Tags: java, configuration, hadoop

I've been trying to use a pagerank algorithm with hadoop and I have some problems with the initialization of jobs.

When I try to make the initialization using Job class I have the following error on compilation:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.(Job.java:89)
    at Pagerank.main(Pagerank.java:244)

Here is the code:

```
Job job;
job = new Job();
job.setJarByClass(Pagerank.class);      // In what class are our map/reduce functions for this job found?
job.setMapperClass(PRMap.class);        // What is our map function for this job?
job.setReducerClass(PRReduce.class);    // What is our reduce function for this job?

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);              // What are the (hadoop.io compliant) datatype for our
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);            // reducer output's key-value pairs?
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);     // How will the mapper distinguish (key value) record inputs?
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0])); // First command line argument
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("temp0"));
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

When I try to make the initialization using JobConf Class I get an error concerning the arguements on some of the methods used.

Here is the code:

```
     JobConf conf = new JobConf(Pagerank.class);
     conf.setJobName("pagerank");

     conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

     conf.setMapperClass(PRMap.class);
     conf.setReducerClass(PRReduce.class);

     conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
     conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

     JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

According to the error:

method setMapperClass in class JobConf cannot be applied to given types;

required: Class ?extends Mapper

found: Class PRMap

reason: actual argument Class PRMap  cannot be converted to Class ?extends Mapper  by method invocation conversion

it seems that I cannot pass PRMap.class as arguement in setMapperClass even though the PRMap class i wrote follows the Map function standard by Hadoop

```
public static class PRMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
{ ... }
```

Any advice on those two approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the jar containing org.apache.commons.Logging.LogFactory jar in to the Lib directory of the HadoopHome of every machine and restart the cluster.

Or you can try adding the jar through the command line using libjars option.
as:

> hadoop jar myjar.jar package.classname -libjars mypath/common-loggings.jar

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in Your Main Method.

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("<Absolute Path>/common-loggings.jar"), conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the PRMap class extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html and the class that needs to be passed through JobConf should be a subclass of org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper.

To fix the problem of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError , add  commons-logging-x.x.x.jar to your classpath .

Run hadoop classpath to confirm if you see the jar showing up.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Mapper is not able to find `LogFactory` , which is part of `common-loggings.jar`. For that you have to make it accessible to every client mapper, By either copying jar to all machines or other efficient  way is to copy into distributed cache by.

```
$bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal mylib.jar /myapp/mylib.jar
And accessing it from you code
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/myapp/mylib.jar"), job);
```

More can be found [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html)